# CSS media query print:

Tags: css

Doing a page, html result like:

```
<div class="container table-page">
    <div class="selected-block"> some info here </div>

    <h1>Table header</h1>

    <div class="notice-calc print-shown">Notices !</div>

    <table class="input-data">...</table>

    <button class="js-btn-add-row">Add row to a input table</button>

    <button class="js-calculate">Calculate table values</button>

    <div class="js-waiting" style="display: none;">Progress bar</div>

    <table class="calc-result" style="display:none;">...</table>
</div>
```

Main idea of styles below - hide every direct children of '.container' except tables and some table elements with class="print-hidden" will be hidden too. For print version of page using rule:

```
@media print {
    .container> :not(table),
    .print-hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    .print-shown {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Later added notices must be shown at print version too, but it does not appear. Nevertheless if edit '.print-shown' rule like:

```
    .container .print-shown {
        display: block;
    }
```

Then it shows. Tested in Chrome 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit)/ Dev.Firefox 86.0b9 (64x)/ Opera 74.0.3911.107. And Edge shows it in both cases.

Why single class selector does not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this selector:

```css
.container > :not(table)
```

It targets all direct children of `.container` (which is not a table). This also includes children with the `.print-shown`-class.

So, when you have a `.print-shown` element as a child of `.container`, the `.container > :not(table)` has presedence over the `.print-shown` class (because the first selector is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#specificity_2) than the latter)

Comment: Based on Your answer digged this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and https://specifishity.com/ (awesome name :D). Thanks for a direction!

Comment: That is correct! I've updated the answer to include a reference to this 